# Estoy usando Psycopg2 pero obtengo un mensaje de error pude ser porque estoy usando Window10?

Tags: python, django

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import psycopg2
import pprint
import sys

def main():
    #Variable conexion
    cadenaConexion="host=localhost dbname=test1 user=postgres 
    password=admin"

    print("Cadena conexion a la BD\n ->%s"%(cadenaConexion))
    obj=psycopg2.connect(cadenaConexion)
    objCursor=obj.cursor()
    objCursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbltext(num, data) VALUES(%s,%s)",
    (26,"Enrique Cortez"))
    obj.commit()
    objCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblTest")
    registros=objCursor.fetchall()
    pprint.pprint(registros)
    #objCursor.close()
    #obj.close()

main()
```

Si ejecuto el codigo anterior obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Angel\Documents\Django pruebas\postgreSQL\1_.py 
=====
Cadena conexion a la BD
->host=localhost dbname=test1 user=postgres password=admin

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Angel\Documents\Django pruebas\postgreSQL\1_.py", line 20, in 
<module>
main()

File "C:\Users\Angel\Documents\Django pruebas\postgreSQL\1_.py", line 10, in 
main
obj=psycopg2.connect(cadenaConexion)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in 
connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

OperationalError: FATAL:  la autentificaciÃ³n password fallÃ³ para el 
usuario Â«postgresÂ»
```

A que puede deberse mi problema?

Comment: basicamente te esta diciendo que esa no es la contraseña del usuario

Comment: Gracias German tenia dias con eso y si comprendía lo que me decía el error pero no sabia como solucionarlo, ya cambie el password en la cadena de conexión por mi contraseña en postgreSQL y quedo solucionado el problema. Gracias !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si observas el último mensaje te dice:

```
FATAL:  la autentificación password falló para el 
usuario postgres
```

Básicamente eso significa que sí detecta el usuario pero que la contraseña que has introducido es incorrecta.
Puede darse el caso de que hayas introducido la contraseña mal cuando has creado el usuario. Prueba a establecer de nuevo la contraseña asegurándote de que estás en la base de datos `test1`.

Para ello conéctate a ella con `psql -U postgres -d test1` y una vez te hayas conectado introduce:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'admin';
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Gracias Marcos tenia dias con eso y si comprendía lo que me decía el error pero no sabia como solucionarlo, ya cambie el password en la cadena de conexión por mi contraseña en postgreSQL y quedo solucionado el problema. Gracias !

Comment: @AngelVargas, si te sirvió la respuesta de Marco, considera marcarla como aceptada, haciendo clic en la marcha de check/paloma que se encuentra del lado izquierdo de la respuesta, justo debajo de la votación.